# Javascript: How to find max N timestamps in time interval from timestamp array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I need to pan and zoom through a large amount of timestamped data.  There is too much data to bind it all to the dom or the browser would bog down.  The timestamped data is ordered smallest to largest.

So the idea is to find the data that fits between the start and end time points on the displayed x axis and thin this down to a reasonable amount N for the browser to handle.

This could be done by dividing the interval between the start and stop points into N amount of reference timestamps, then find the timestamp in the data closest to each reference.

I can code this up, but probably not as efficiently as an existing solution.

Is there a library, possibly crossfilter, that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ordered array of data and you are searching for arbitrary points within the data. Your optimal search algorithm is a binary search, which will find the indexes of the begin and end points in O(log(n)) time.

Underscore.js has an implementation of binary search: http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf

Don't know about crossfilter, but check their range filter.

Once you have the begin and end indexes you know how many points are between them. Then you can decide how to thin. There is no one right answer for how to thin, it depends on the data and the story you're telling. You can sample every nth point, you can average or max partitions, or many other options.

However you chose to thin, crossplot can do it with "grouping" (e.g., into equal-width partitions) and then "reducing" the groups.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems reasonable.   I do have to write my own binary search because I'm not looking for exact match, just the nearest to a timestamp.

Comment: In that case, look at sortedIndex.

It tells you the index that your value would be inserted at (using binary search).

Comment: Thanks, I did try sortedIndex.  It's twice as fast as my version.